# How to simulate/test key press using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, use-effect

I'm trying to simulate/test the keypress event which calls `props.onClick`. I successfully simulated the `onClick` with similar testing code, but the keypress doesn't work.

When I tested it manually by pressing the Enter key, it works as it should, but when I try to write tests for it, it keeps failing and I'm not sure why. I put a logger in the `useEffect` function, and it gets called during the test, but it fails and gives an error that `onClickFnc` was never called.

In my button function component, I bind an event listener:

**button.js**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (enterEnable) {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', onEnterPress);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', onEnterPress);
    }
  });

  const onEnterPress = e => {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      onClickSync(e);
    }
  };

  const onClickSync = e => {
    props.onClick(e);
  };
```

**button.test.js**

```
  it('check ButtonLoader enable enter to work', () => {

    const onClickFnc = jest.fn(); 
    const wrapper = shallow(<ButtonLoader {...props} enterEnable={true} onClick={onClickFnc}/>);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter'})
    expect(onClickFnc).toBeCalled();
  });
```

**Error:**

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

How can I successfully test this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
wrapper.find('button').simulate('keydown', {which: 13})
```

From what I have seen, simulate doesn't create an event object from the arguments. Instead it passes the object as is.

Comment: unfortunately, it still gives the same error that the function wasn't called

Comment: Looks like there is some issues with attaching [event handler to windows](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/426). May I ask, why are you not adding the handler to the button using `<button onKeyDown={onEnterPress}>`? As simulate doesn't create a proper event, it would not bubble up.

Comment: theres a prop `enterEnable` that controls whether the keydown event listener is enabled, as shown in the useEffect. But now that you mentioned it, would it be bad practice to control that in `onEnterPress`, instead of having a global event listener?

Comment: I could also control which 'key' triggers the event handler, as I only want the `Enter` key to trigger it.

Comment: `wrapper.find(...).simulate is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
    element.simulate('keydown', { key: 'Enter' });
```

this worked fine for me. hope it also works for you.